# Jenkins integration with AD

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins

I am working on integrating a new Jenkins instance with AD. I have installed the required plugins. When I try to add a domain, it asks for info such as domain name, domain controller, etc.

I am not fully clear on the BindDN field. If I leave it blank and test the domain, it throws this warning

> Leaving blank `Bind DN` means that any operation performed will use anonymous binding. Keep in mind that this is not recommended as some servers do not allow it by default.

I then provided a user account in BindDN which exists in the domain. Now on testing the domain, it is throwing this error log:

> DC_Name:389
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: DC_Name
>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

Pls share some inputs to complete the integration with AD.

Answer (score 0):

There is information provided in the [Jenkins wiki page for the AD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin), as well as some ldap tools to help diagnose.

> `<DOMAIN_NAME>` -> Domain Name: `support-cloudbees.com`
>   `<searchbase>` -> Organization Unit we want to look into.
>  
>      In the example, it is `OU=Support, DC=support-cloudbees, DC=com`
>   `<binddn>` -> Bind DN.
>      In the example, `CN=felix, OU=Support, DC=support-cloudbees, DC=com`
>   `<passwd>` -> Bind Password
>   `<userid>` -> User we want to look for. We can look for the managerDN itself or for a different user on the tree.
>      In the  example, this can be set-up for example to `CN=felix, OU=Support, DC=support-cloudbees, DC=com`.

As [described here](https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.howto41996.html),

> The **Bind DN** is comprised of the **user and the location of the user in
>   the LDAP directory tree**. **Each element of the Distinguished Name is
>   pointed out**: The first part is the user CN=user1. The second part is
>   the container CN=Users. The third part is the domain DC=example and
>   DC=com

Did you correctly  specify "the location of the user in the LDAP tree" ? The error appears to be with a **DC** value.

Ours is in the form:
`cn=<Acct Name>, ou=<some_value>, ou=<some_value>, dc=<some_value>, dc=<some_value>`

YMMV. Try use the ldap tools mentioned to validate.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks so much for the response. I have updated the BindDN to provide the name of an AD account in the format which you suggested. I was able to find the info from ADSI Edit tool. I also provided the password of this account in the Bind Password field. I am still seeing the same error of UnknownHost. Does the user provided in BindDN need to belong to a certain group in AD?

Comment: Well, I suppose it needs to be an account that can also see the rest of the users that will be authenticating.I don't recall requesting anything special from our AD teams when set it up. Maybe rephrase the question (or new) as an AD question ?